# React Native duplicate debug ios config not working

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am trying to figure out how to make new ios configs work with a React Native app. Specifically, for now, new Debug configs. I have a brand new app, and I have duplicated the ios `Debug` config to `Debug2`. When I run `npx react-native run-ios` it works as expected, because it picks up the `Debug` config. When I run `npx react-native run-ios --configuration Debug2`, it builds the app successfully and installs it on the simulator, but the app immediately crashes, with a crash report like this:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x1037817bc __exceptionPreprocess + 160
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x101209144 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   MultiConfigDemo                        0x1002751a4 RCTGetFatalHandler + 0 (RCTAssert.m:161)
3   MultiConfigDemo                        0x10028b228 __28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke + 608
4   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1015b1fa4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1015b3768 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1015c3018 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1220
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1015c2b44 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 40
8   CoreFoundation                         0x1036e5ca4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
9   CoreFoundation                         0x1036e0360 __CFRunLoopRun + 1956
10  CoreFoundation                         0x1036df7a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
11  GraphicsServices                       0x105a9fc98 GSEventRunModal + 160
12  UIKitCore                              0x11921237c -[UIApplication _run] + 868
13  UIKitCore                              0x119216374 UIApplicationMain + 124
14  MultiConfigDemo                        0x1001fc0f0 main + 100 (main.m:8)
15  dyld_sim                               0x100b11fa0 start_sim + 20
16  dyld                                   0x100bf1f28 start + 2236
17  ???                             0xe156000000000000 ???
```

The repo is here: https://github.com/tsargent/rn-multi-config-demo

Note that there are only 2 commits added after the initial commit of running `npx react-native init MultiConfigDemo`:

- https://github.com/tsargent/rn-multi-config-demo/commit/f8ba31404b6e5c130f45f816692dcce92a741934 this commit adds the `Debug2` config, which is a duplicate of the `Debug` config. No settings have changed within this config.
- https://github.com/tsargent/rn-multi-config-demo/commit/eece7e26eea97d498d516f99626039586288dd4b this commit adds the changes after an `npx pod-install`

I am on Xcode 14.2, with an M1 chip.

I have also tried to add this in my Podfile, as suggested by some articles:

```rb
project 'MultiConfigDemo', 'Debug2' => :debug
```

but this gives me linking errors when I attempt to build Debug2:

```
▸ Running script '[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock'
▸ Running script 'Start Packager'
▸ Compiling AppDelegate.mm
▸ Compiling MultiConfigDemo_vers.c
▸ Compiling main.m
▸ Linking MultiConfigDemo

❌  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64



❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Note that I did not commit that Podfile change to the repo, as I'm not sure if that's the right direction.

Has anyone had luck with creating duplicate Debug configs like this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out.

In the Podfile, I need to add this:

```rb
project 'MultiConfigDemo',
  'Debug2' => :debug
```

And then I need to enable Flipper for that new configuration. When Flipper is enabled, it is enabled for only Debug by default, I think https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native/#using-the-latest-flipper-sdk
So we can enable it for both Debug and Debug2 like this:

```rb
FlipperConfiguration.enabled(['Debug', 'Debug2'])
```

Now Debug2 works as expected.

The new commits were added to the repo here https://github.com/tsargent/rn-multi-config-demo/commit/27122825fb2be7931ae2f734b5d51021c1c5ff5b